# make systemd pager not do horizontal scroll, and wrap to next line instead

Tags: systemd, terminal

By default systemd (v245) on Ubuntu 20.04 focal, if I do `systemctl status $THING`, and the output lines are longer than my screen, then the default pager (less?) will do horizontal scrolling. I would rather the extra text be on the following lines ("word wrap")

what environmental variable can I set to make this change from horizontal scrolling to "put the remainder of the line on the next line"?

I know that `systemctl --no-pager $THING` or `systemctl status $THING | cat` will work in this case, but that's extra text to type every time. I want `systemctl status $THING` to always work without having to add extra bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make no-pager permanent by exporting an empty environment variable `SYSTEMD_PAGER`, i.e.:

```
export SYSTEMD_PAGER=
```

But you will notice that now systemd ellipsizes the long lines, so you must also turn this off with the `-l`, `--full` command line option. There's no environment variable to change this, unfortunately.

---

For a complete solution I would suggest a shell alias for `systemctl`, such as:

```
alias systemctl='systemctl --no-pager --full'
```

Answer (score 9):

By default, `systemctl` spawns `less` as the pager (if it is available, but on most systems, it is). In this case, `less` is given the parameters `FRSXMK`, of which `S` is responsible for not folding long lines.

If the `SYSTEMD_LESS` environment variable is set, its contents are handled as the flags to be given to `less`, if `less` is the pager currently in use. So if you omit the `S` flag from the variable, and do an

```
export SYSTEMD_LESS="FRXMK"
```

then `systemctl` will behave exactly as before, except it will fold long lines.

It might be worth noting that you can switch line folding within `less` by typing `-S` and pressing enter.